# Solr4.6 is this possible to use common configuration file for multiple cores?

Tags: solr, multicore

I am Migrating solr from solr3.5 TO Solr4.10
In that solr.xml configuration changes.

Upto 4.2 there are as support to use common configuration (instanceDir) file for multiple cores.
Ex.:

```
<cores adminPath="/admin/cores" defaultCoreName="CoreName">
    <core name="core1" dataDir="data/core1/" instanceDir="." />
    <core name="core2" dataDir="data/core2/" instanceDir="." />
    <core name="core_3" dataDir="data/core3/" instanceDir="." config="solrconfig_newCore.xml" schema="schema_newCore.xml" />
    <core name="core_4" dataDir="data/core4/" instanceDir="." config="solrconfig_newCore.xml" schema="schema_newCore.xml" />
    .....
</cores>
```

Now in 4.10 Not support such common configuration (i.e. InstanceDir) file.
while in 5.0 it's mandatory.

Is there any way to use common configuration file for multiple cores?

Like:
conf/ is common with country specific name (schema_fr.xml, etc..) and handle at same place like solr.xml.
just data directory is different.

Comment: Instead of storing the same config files physically, you could use the symbolic links. We do that for configuring the cores.

Comment: Yes, That was one of the idea...
But in this case need to create each core directory and linking them from main conf dir.

Instead If instanceDir solution got, No need to create any core(s) dir. all thing manage using that one instanceDir.

Comment: but you still need to have separate physical locations for your index files per core.

Comment: Yes, For Index it's require, but core file only once and conf file at one location (Might be different name as per language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr5+
We can use common config file using configSets

Can define common configuration file at once place in configsets directory.
Ex.: /solr/configsets/my_configs/conf/ and core.property for individual core as per below:

in core1:
    name=core1
    configSet=my_configs
    schema=schema_my.xml
    config=solrconfig_my.xml

in core2:
    name=core2
    configSet=my_configs
    schema=schema_new.xml
    config=solrconfig_new.xml

in core3:
    name=core3
    configSet=my_configs
    schema=schema_test.xml
    config=solrconfig_my.xml

So, In that data directory individual core but configset at once place to manage.